# R: How to decrease counter in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, decrement

I would like to do 10 iterations, but sometimes flag is bigger that 1. In this case I must to decrease variable i by 1 and calculate flag again. How to do this decrement?

```
    for(i in (1:n)){ 
    flag <- ... # some code
        if (flag > 1) {
         # some code
        } 
        #else decrement i <- i - 1 ??
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: @yeouuu thanks for reply. Language is "R". else {i--} does not work.

Comment: for the record to have a true decreasing for loop simply change `1:n` to `n:1`.

Answer (score 6):

That's what a while loop is for, not for loop.

```
i <- 1
while(i <= 10)
{
  i <- i + 1 #
  flag <- ... # some code
  if (flag > 1) {
    # some code
  } 
  else{
    i <- #some arbitrary number    
  }
}
```

Do note however that you may end up in infinite loop if you are not careful.

Comment: `i <- #some arbitrary number` should be probably `i <- i - 1` to make this clearer.

Comment: @DavidArenburg If that was i - 1 it would be much better to do a `continue` before incrementing the flag.

Comment: @DavidArenburg But yeah, you're right. I'd be happy to clarify it if OP clarifies his question.